# NodeJS memory leak using Buffer that are created manually

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks, buffer

I am trying to create buffer data to be sent over a socket. (The receiving party needs it to be buffer only). So to create a final buffer to send I am creating different buffers in between and then concat them to generate the last buffer to send. Another tricky thing here is that I need to calculate and send buffer lengths separately as well. Please find the code below:

```
function BufferGenerator() {
  this.generateData = generateData;
  this.sendData = sendData;
  //....
}
function generateData(requestObj, params, paramsLength) {
  let uBuf = Buffer.from(requestObj.user.login);
  let passBuf = Buffer.from(requestObj.user.pass);
  let nameBuf = Buffer.from(requestObj.user.name);
  const MsgLen = uBuf.length + passBuf.length + nameBuf.length + paramsLength;
  return Buffer.concat([uBuf, passBuf, nameBuf]);
}

function sendData(requestObj, data) {
  const pBufs = [];
  let pLength = 0;
    _.forEach(data, function (value, key) { // this usually has ~15-20 items in data.
      const kBuf = Buffer.from(key);
      const kLengthBuf = Buffer.alloc(4);
      kLengthBuf.writeInt32LE(key.length);

      const vBuf = Buffer.from(value);
      const valBufLength = Buffer.alloc(4);
      valBufLength.writeInt32LE(value.length);

      pLength += kLengthBuf.length + valBufLength.length + kBuf.length + vBuf.length;
      pBufs.push(kLengthBuf, valBufLength, kBuf, vBuf);
    });
  const finalBuf = this.generateData(requestObj, Buffer.concat(pBufs), pLength);
  this.sendToChannel(finalBuf);
}
```

Now when I run the application normally, things work well. But when I run it in the performance test, 100 concurrent requests per second, the application slowly starts to eat more and more memory and eventually memory overflow exception is thrown. After digging I found 2 possible things for this memory leak or memory overflow:

1. The buffers I am creating are not properly garbage collected, because when I comment that part of code, there is no memory overflow or leaks.
2. The Scavenge event is fired frequently in GC but does not clear the complete allocated memory. In between I also see Mark-sweep events from GC, this event does clear more memory but at the end there is still some left which slowly adds up and eventually, memory overflow is seen.

Btw, when the load is stopped the memory starts to fall down drastically, although I can see some memory addition to the starting memory. For instance, the starting memory is 18 MB, when the load is started, I can see it increasing and going up to 100MB, after that if I stop the load then it will drop back to ~20MB in just a few seconds and a bunch of GC logs gets printed very fast.

For my performance test (100 users), I can see memory out of bound exception in about ~8 minutes.

I tried below things so far:

- Use heapdump npm to generate various dumps and compare them. No major luck here, 2 things identified here are already listed above.
- Made the buffer objects null manually. This did not change anything.
- Use buffer objects as global in class and then delete them (delete this.uBuf) instead of assigning to null.

Can someone please help here and suggest a way by which I can clear the memory and avoid out of bound errors?

**EDIT 1**

Last few mark-sweep logs:

```
/Users/harsh.r/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node --trace_gc --expose_gc --trace-gc-ignore-scavenger --max-old-space-size=128 --max-semi-space-size=2 server.js
[20904:0x10264a000]      717 ms: Mark-sweep 11.6 (18.9) -> 9.2 (18.4) MB, 2.6 / 0.2 ms  (+ 4.4 ms in 7 steps since start of marking, biggest step 2.6 ms, walltime since start of marking 58 ms) (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]     1334 ms: Mark-sweep 22.0 (27.9) -> 19.1 (27.8) MB, 2.6 / 0.4 ms  (+ 3.3 ms in 9 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.7 ms, walltime since start of marking 86 ms) (average mu = 0.991, current mu = 0.991) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]    19206 ms: Mark-sweep 28.0 (34.8) -> 23.3 (35.3) MB, 2.9 / 0.0 ms  (+ 4.7 ms in 13 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.8 ms, walltime since start of marking 462 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]    39027 ms: Mark-sweep 31.8 (37.3) -> 23.9 (37.3) MB, 2.8 / 0.0 ms  (+ 3.7 ms in 8 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 182 ms) (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]    50313 ms: Mark-sweep 28.5 (37.8) -> 22.9 (31.8) MB, 6.2 / 0.0 ms  (+ 4.6 ms in 11 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 530 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]    61607 ms: Mark-sweep 28.4 (33.3) -> 23.1 (33.3) MB, 1.7 / 0.0 ms  (+ 6.5 ms in 14 steps since start of marking, biggest step 4.2 ms, walltime since start of marking 642 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]    77427 ms: Mark-sweep 30.9 (39.3) -> 24.1 (39.3) MB, 1.4 / 0.0 ms  (+ 3.9 ms in 16 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.5 ms, walltime since start of marking 750 ms) (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]    95941 ms: Mark-sweep 32.2 (40.3) -> 24.5 (40.3) MB, 1.8 / 0.0 ms  (+ 7.6 ms in 14 steps since start of marking, biggest step 2.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 431 ms) (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   114741 ms: Mark-sweep 34.4 (42.3) -> 26.1 (42.3) MB, 3.1 / 0.0 ms  (+ 4.7 ms in 17 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.8 ms, walltime since start of marking 221 ms) (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   137120 ms: Mark-sweep 34.3 (44.8) -> 26.2 (45.3) MB, 3.8 / 0.0 ms  (+ 11.1 ms in 17 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.7 ms, walltime since start of marking 249 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   156384 ms: Mark-sweep 36.1 (48.3) -> 27.9 (48.3) MB, 2.8 / 0.1 ms  (+ 5.2 ms in 14 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 456 ms) (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   173797 ms: Mark-sweep 35.0 (49.3) -> 27.2 (35.8) MB, 13.4 / 0.1 ms  (+ 6.0 ms in 16 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 722 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   176049 ms: Mark-sweep 29.5 (36.8) -> 28.1 (33.8) MB, 9.9 / 0.0 ms  (+ 5.5 ms in 9 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.7 ms, walltime since start of marking 260 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.993) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   187301 ms: Mark-sweep 32.6 (37.8) -> 28.3 (37.8) MB, 1.7 / 0.0 ms  (+ 20.7 ms in 9 steps since start of marking, biggest step 11.5 ms, walltime since start of marking 164 ms) (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.998) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   206234 ms: Mark-sweep 36.4 (44.8) -> 28.8 (44.8) MB, 1.7 / 0.0 ms  (+ 5.8 ms in 13 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 336 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   226766 ms: Mark-sweep 36.9 (47.3) -> 29.3 (47.3) MB, 2.0 / 0.0 ms  (+ 5.1 ms in 15 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.7 ms, walltime since start of marking 588 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   246911 ms: Mark-sweep 39.2 (49.8) -> 30.7 (50.3) MB, 4.7 / 0.0 ms  (+ 7.1 ms in 15 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.4 ms, walltime since start of marking 265 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   275394 ms: Mark-sweep 39.0 (52.3) -> 30.9 (52.3) MB, 4.1 / 0.0 ms  (+ 5.2 ms in 16 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 709 ms) (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   295820 ms: Mark-sweep 38.4 (51.8) -> 31.2 (37.8) MB, 25.9 / 0.0 ms  (+ 8.1 ms in 13 steps since start of marking, biggest step 2.4 ms, walltime since start of marking 873 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.998) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   297405 ms: Mark-sweep 33.2 (38.8) -> 31.8 (38.3) MB, 3.7 / 0.0 ms  (+ 5.7 ms in 16 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.2 ms, walltime since start of marking 239 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.994) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   319076 ms: Mark-sweep 40.5 (48.3) -> 32.9 (48.3) MB, 3.2 / 0.0 ms  (+ 7.1 ms in 14 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.5 ms, walltime since start of marking 280 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   340409 ms: Mark-sweep 42.6 (50.8) -> 33.7 (50.8) MB, 10.8 / 0.1 ms  (+ 9.8 ms in 14 steps since start of marking, biggest step 3.1 ms, walltime since start of marking 467 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   348817 ms: Mark-sweep 37.8 (51.8) -> 33.5 (51.8) MB, 31.8 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.996) heap profiler GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   348850 ms: Mark-sweep 33.5 (51.8) -> 33.3 (50.8) MB, 33.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.996, current mu = 0.001) heap profiler GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   368660 ms: Mark-sweep 42.0 (52.3) -> 34.4 (52.8) MB, 7.9 / 0.0 ms  (+ 5.1 ms in 14 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.9 ms, walltime since start of marking 330 ms) (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   389645 ms: Mark-sweep 43.2 (54.8) -> 34.5 (55.3) MB, 4.1 / 0.0 ms  (+ 4.9 ms in 15 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.8 ms, walltime since start of marking 548 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   407648 ms: Mark-sweep 43.8 (57.3) -> 35.2 (57.3) MB, 9.5 / 0.0 ms  (+ 4.5 ms in 16 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.7 ms, walltime since start of marking 531 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   421509 ms: Mark-sweep 41.3 (59.8) -> 35.7 (59.8) MB, 49.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.996) heap profiler GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   421555 ms: Mark-sweep 35.7 (59.8) -> 35.7 (59.8) MB, 45.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.001) heap profiler GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   444721 ms: Mark-sweep 44.3 (61.8) -> 36.5 (61.8) MB, 10.1 / 0.0 ms  (+ 6.1 ms in 14 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 427 ms) (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   466438 ms: Mark-sweep 44.4 (63.8) -> 37.0 (63.8) MB, 2.9 / 0.0 ms  (+ 17.9 ms in 13 steps since start of marking, biggest step 12.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 536 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   490390 ms: Mark-sweep 46.5 (65.8) -> 38.2 (66.3) MB, 5.6 / 0.0 ms  (+ 5.4 ms in 15 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 585 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   508953 ms: Mark-sweep 45.8 (68.3) -> 38.4 (68.3) MB, 60.6 / 8.5 ms  (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.997) heap profiler GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   509004 ms: Mark-sweep 38.4 (68.3) -> 38.2 (68.3) MB, 51.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.002) heap profiler GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   536930 ms: Mark-sweep 47.0 (70.3) -> 39.9 (70.8) MB, 21.1 / 0.0 ms  (+ 10.5 ms in 20 steps since start of marking, biggest step 3.6 ms, walltime since start of marking 61 ms) (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   572032 ms: Mark-sweep 47.9 (72.8) -> 40.2 (72.8) MB, 13.1 / 0.7 ms  (+ 13.0 ms in 9 steps since start of marking, biggest step 4.4 ms, walltime since start of marking 236 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   590105 ms: Mark-sweep 49.1 (74.8) -> 41.0 (74.8) MB, 5.0 / 0.0 ms  (+ 13.7 ms in 9 steps since start of marking, biggest step 8.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 73 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   609718 ms: Mark-sweep 49.2 (76.8) -> 41.3 (76.8) MB, 25.2 / 0.0 ms  (+ 10.0 ms in 10 steps since start of marking, biggest step 2.9 ms, walltime since start of marking 64 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.998) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   629874 ms: Mark-sweep 50.6 (78.8) -> 41.7 (78.8) MB, 6.4 / 0.1 ms  (+ 7.2 ms in 5 steps since start of marking, biggest step 3.6 ms, walltime since start of marking 204 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   649548 ms: Mark-sweep 51.2 (80.8) -> 43.0 (81.3) MB, 9.9 / 0.0 ms  (+ 6.7 ms in 13 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.8 ms, walltime since start of marking 193 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.999) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   672509 ms: Mark-sweep 51.5 (83.8) -> 43.4 (83.8) MB, 4.9 / 0.0 ms  (+ 4.7 ms in 6 steps since start of marking, biggest step 2.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 199 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 1.000) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   684486 ms: Mark-sweep 52.0 (84.8) -> 40.2 (84.8) MB, 18.8 / 0.0 ms  (+ 11.2 ms in 23 steps since start of marking, biggest step 3.1 ms, walltime since start of marking 40 ms) (average mu = 0.999, current mu = 0.997) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   685065 ms: Mark-sweep 53.3 (84.8) -> 29.9 (81.3) MB, 9.0 / 0.0 ms  (+ 9.6 ms in 25 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.6 ms, walltime since start of marking 29 ms) (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.968) finalize incremental marking via task GC in old space requested
```

We can see the memory is growing slowly, even though mark-sweep events are happening.

Once I stop the load the logs become:

```
[20904:0x10264a000]   685065 ms: Mark-sweep 53.3 (84.8) -> 29.9 (81.3) MB, 9.0 / 0.0 ms  (+ 9.6 ms in 25 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.6 ms, walltime since start of marking 29 ms) (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.968) finalize incremental marking via task GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   708577 ms: Mark-sweep 39.0 (81.3) -> 21.6 (31.3) MB, 45.7 / 0.0 ms  (+ 11.4 ms in 16 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.2 ms, walltime since start of marking 58 ms) (average mu = 0.998, current mu = 0.998) finalize incremental marking via task GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   709610 ms: Mark-sweep 21.6 (31.3) -> 21.4 (27.3) MB, 12.9 / 0.0 ms  (+ 15.9 ms in 17 steps since start of marking, biggest step 2.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 29 ms) (average mu = 0.996, current mu = 0.972) finalize incremental marking via task GC in old space requested
[20904:0x10264a000]   710632 ms: Mark-sweep 21.4 (27.3) -> 21.4 (27.3) MB, 6.6 / 0.0 ms  (+ 11.0 ms in 14 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.6 ms, walltime since start of marking 18 ms) (average mu = 0.995, current mu = 0.983) finalize incremental marking via task GC in old space requested
```

The memory came down.

Comment: Well, a memory leak doesn't seem to be your problem. What is the logic behind this piece of code? Why do you need to buffer at all?

Comment: @JonasWilms The opposite party on the socket needs it to be buffer only and can not change that as its a legacy third party implementation that we are using. We need to compulsory share buffers only. And the logic is to convert data received in the request into buffers and send it over the socket to other party. What it does is to loop over and create <key, value> buffer pairs  for the data received in db query along with request data received as buffers.